# Interrupted downloads

Tags: windows-7, browser, download, connection, internet-connection

I've been having troubles with my internet connection within these sites:

(I'm using `Firefox 6.0, Chrome 13.0.782.112, I.E 9.0 Latest version`, and is the same problem with all those browsers, for downloading, I've used download manager systems too.)

**[www.youtube.com](http://www.youtube.com)** Sometimes when I'm seeing a video, after some seconds or minutes these is interrupted and the loading bar below, seems that the video is completely loaded  but no, the video has been stooped.

**[www.Apple.com](http://www.apple.com/itunes/)** I'm trying to download (manually) the iTunes program, but it's interrupted when is downloading (Not have precisely break moment). I been trying to downloading it from the iTunes (updating) but still the same problem.

**[www.AMD.com](http://support.AMD.com/us/gpudownload/Windows/Legacy/Pages/integrated_Vista32.aspx?type=2.7&product=2.7.2.3.2&lang=English)**  Same as the above but with an ATI driver.

The curious thing is that I've downloaded files of 500mb from **www.megaupload.com** and works perfectly. Which tells that maybe are the servers of that websites, but isn't just 1 site, maybe can occur with other sites that I don't use.

- No router, direct connection.
- I've reset the modem (Settings by default)
- I've changed the Ethernet cable
- I've formatted the PC (No antivirus at the moment)
- I've disabled the firewall
- Drivers Updated.
- Windows 7 Home Premium(Updated)
- ISP: Megacable [Cable]

I don't know if is the modem, problem connection with my ISP, servers of the services that I'm using, or hardware issue. The problem occur at any time of the day. One night i've sucessful dowloaded the itunes program, then i've instantly tried again but it couldn't download again (Seems that at night is less, but not totally).

Comment: I really doubt its the services you are using.

Comment: @soandos So you think that it isn't my problem?

Comment: megaupload limits the speed while others don't. Speed might be the problem?

Comment: It sounds like your connection is dropping for a short time. Megaupload may have a longer timeout period.

Comment: @soandos Any way to fix it?

Comment: I would make sure that is the problem first. There are probably better ways of doing it, but I would just continuously ping something (google.com) an output the data to a log file (in cmd: `Ping address -t >logfilelocation`). Then see if the ping ever fails.

Comment: @soandos done but, i dont know read it. *-*

Comment: look at the log file for timed out, unable to resolve address, unable to reach host, things like that

Comment: packages: sended = 317, recieved= 317, lost = 0
    (0% lost),

    Min = 43ms, Max = 67ms, Av = 45ms

Comment: @soandos let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1140/discussion-between-neannam-and-soandos)

Comment: @nEAnnam Please consider that you shouldn't accept an answer that didn't even work for you. If your question is marked as "answered", people won't look at it anymore, because they'll think you don't have any problem to solve.

Comment: What is your ISP and is it DSL, Cable, or something else (like cellular or satellite)? What times of day do you experience this or is it at all times of the day? Have you tried doing these things at different times of the day? Also, if you don't have an Antivirus, I recommend you get one soon, just as a general tip (it shouldn't hurt your problem here, but it also shouldn't affect it otherwise, either).

Comment: @sidran Thanks for the suggestion, im just put that i dont have antivirus for the firewall issue, no problem with the antivirus, an i've added that things you mentioned above. Thanks :)

Comment: Please don't edit "[Solved]" into your title. The fact that you have accepted an answer tells us that you have got a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cable Internet is very sensitive to the usage in your area. You will typically see slower Internet speeds during the day and on weekends, when people are at home, and better connection quality and speeds during the night when most people are asleep. However, if there is someone on your network that is using a lot of bandwidth constantly and isn't being throttled, then you may feel the brunt of that. BitTorrent is a popular protocol for file-sharing that very easily and quickly can take over the available bandwidth for a network. I am unaware of Cablevision's network congestion practices, but it could be that you have a few very bandwidth intensive users in your network that is causing network quality to degrade for other users. This could explain why it happens at all times of the day. Is this the case for your neighbors? I would also call the Cable company and see if they know of anything based on their network usage monitoring tools.

It also is possible that your cables are of poor quality. You mentioned that you changed the Ethernet cable, but your coaxial cables could also cause issues. Especially if you have splitters in use for cable extension but no terminators. You could be getting noise which could affect your Internet connection. All coaxial cables aren't equal. Older ones may not have the proper shielding for maintaining a good network signal. Check the cable wiring in your house, or have your cable company send someone down to do this. It could be poor wiring.

Comment: Wow I did not know about the issue that you can affect the bandwidth for other users, nice point. About the coaxial cable, i've called to my ISP and requested a new Coaxial cable connection, i'll see if that works. I will test those servers mentioned above in another locations and see if works. Whenever i solve the problem, i will post the solution. Thanks for your help, Besides, did you know how to test if works my red components?

Comment: @nEAnnam You're welcome! And which components do you mean by "red components"?

Comment: Red Peripherals, For example this:  Realtek RTL8110 Gigabit Ethernet

Comment: @nEAnnam Red components or peripherals is not a common term. The component that you listed is your Ethernet interface. Is it literally listed somewhere in a red color? I am still unsure of what you mean.

Comment: LOL sorry, in my country, we use to refer Red as Network, sorry. But yeah is there any way to see if works the Ethernet interface of my pc? is integrated at the motherboard.

Comment: @nEAnnam Aha, I see. To be able to see if it works properly, the easiest way to test it is to verify that it gets an IP from a device (like your modem or router), and then is able to connect to other computers and transfer data. Since you have some Internet connectivity, it appears to be working. Windows' configuration of Internet-related services may affect connection quality, but Windows 7's stock settings at boot should work fine for typical users.

Comment: So will be the coaxial cable i think, there isn't other things that affect to my problem, ill wait until my ISP change it. Thank you very much for your time and wise answer, and if i could do something for you, let me know.

Comment: Well, I hope that this will solve your issue!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use [Internet Download Manager](http://www.internetdownloadmanager.com/), it can solve the problems you are having.

Comment: Still the same but ill give you the answered for for your time and help. thanks :)

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem, it just masks it. You still should get to the root of what is going on, not just put a workaround in place.